# Pass javascript value to controller C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a search function on my website that allows the user to select what table they wnat to search for. The select list is within a dropdown rendered within a dropdown menu using bootstrap. The issue I'm facing is that when the form is run the value of the selected item from the dropdown menu that is passed into the controller is "" instead of the value that was selected in the dropdown menu.

Any help would be grateful.

** search function**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    @{using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Searchv2", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @foreach (var searchType in new[] { "User", "Restaurant", "Cuisine" })
                    {
                        <li><a href="">@searchType</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" name="SearchBy" />
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="SearchString" id="SearchString">
        </div>
    }}
</div>
```

**jquery that finds the value**

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown-menu").click(function () {
        $("input[name='SearchBy']").val($(this).html());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try breaking up that javascript into two lines (the first `var value = $(this).html();`) so you can more easily check what it is you're actually passing into `.val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write click event on anchor tag, as you have anchor tag inside `<li>` like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li>
  <a>SearchText</a>
 </li>
</ul>


$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {


            $("input[name='SearchBy']").val($(this).html());
        });
```

Comment: I have changed the function to $(this).val() but it still doesn't send the vle of SearchBy to the controller

Comment: @Dolaps try the updated solution, this will surely work for you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set the `SearchBy` value by getting the value of the selected item:

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown-menu").click(function () {
        $("input[name='SearchBy']").val($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value of text in between the `<a></a>` tags, try use `.text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 0):

First you are selecting the ul not the a inside its li and second you should use jquery text function:

```
<script>
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[name="SearchBy"]').val($(this).text());
});
</script>
```